# How to insert mysql data or values in excel with side by side using Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, excel, codeigniter-3

I am inserting `Mysql` values in excel  using `Codeigniter` library but i want data in excel should come side by side(in row) not one by one  here i have posted my code which will insert mysql data in excel.

```
$this->load->library("excel");
        $object = new PHPExcel();

        $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $table_columns = array("category", "Total YES Count", "Unit");

foreach($table_columns as $field)
        {
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
            $column++;
        }

        $employee_data = $this->excel_export_model->fetch_data();

        $excel_row = 2;

        foreach($employee_data as $row)
        {

            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row->catname);
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, 'Mandatory M='.$row->count_m .' '.'Essential E='. $row->count_e);
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row->unit_name);
            $excel_row++;
        }
```

Expected output:
**expected output for code**

[image]

Getting output manner:

**getting output**

[image]